# Hibernate Tools "Duplicate class" error on reverse engineering

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am trying to reverse engineer a SQL Server 2005 using Hibernate Tools and am getting a strange error:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinderException: 
     Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated for
     'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints‌​)'. 
     Same name where generated for             
     'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints‌​)' 

    Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated for 
    'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints‌​)'. 
    Same name where generated for 
    'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(e2rm_maintenance_development2.sys.check_constraints‌​)'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A development user has typically access to multiple database schema s with similar tables.
The Generation tool tries to generate output for all those databases and this results in duplicate class names (even if you ask for ddl generation).

Add a 'reveng' setup and limit the output to one database schema.

Also add necessary parameters from the selected 'Exporters'. Some are necessary, but this is not indicated in the overview.

[image: Configure with reveng.xml]

[image: Add necessary variables]

Comment: What should i do after clicking on **Add Exporter Property** ? what should i give for values ??

Comment: Selecting the specific `Database Schema` worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to avoid the error by creating "hibernate.reveng.xml" in which I excluded "sys" and "INFORMATION" schemas and only included "dbo" schema.

Comment: How did you exclude schema please?   I am trying in NB8.02  even with explicit schema & explicit tables still get "'validname.CheckConstraints" on db.sys.check_constraint.

Answer (score 1):

as a continue to Daniil Shevelev answer (this is what worked for me )  in order to exlude schema add new reveng.xml 
then choose new and on the next screen click next -then click refresh on the buttom (takes some time to get the schemas) then stand on the relevant scheme and exclude it 
[image: see picture here]